# YouTube iframe embed displaying video at smaller dimensions than iframe

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

When I attempt to embed a YouTube video as an IFRAME, the video dimensions always appear too small within the video frame when the video plays as HTML 5 Video. It looks fine when viewed in a browser with Flash enabled.

I'm wondering if there's some sort of workaround (that doesn't require Flash)?

The following jsFiddle demonstrates this problem. I've appended "html5=1" to the iframe src URL, which forces the video to play with HTML 5 in Chrome; Firefox seems to ignore the parameter so you'll have to disable Flash to see it.

Here's the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DML2T/

And here's the code you'll find there:

```
<iframe id="videoPlayer1" width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5Rxqv2pYS_U?autoplay=1&html5=1"></iframe>
```

[image: This screenshot shows the annoying black space around the video.]

Comment: Also seeing this issue.

Comment: I think maybe some bad code was pushed to youtube live today because my site now works as does your jsfiddle